# discord.js adding to a an id pulled from a data

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I have quite the weird problem, and I am not exactly sure what to do. This code is not commented yet but:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const db = require('../../config/db');

class Win extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'win',
      group: 'challenge',
      memberName: 'win',
      description: 'Gives rules on mock or legit duels.',
      examples: ['win id user'],
      args: [
        {
          key: 'id',
          prompt: 'You are missing the ID of the challenge.',
          type: 'string',
        },
        {
          key: 'user',
          prompt: 'User needs to be added (the winning user, not the losing!',
          type: 'user',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  run(msg, { id, user }) {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?';
    var userid = msg.author.id;
    db.query(sql, userid, (err, rows) => {
      var ref = rows[0];
      if (ref === undefined) {
        return;
      }
      if (ref.rank <= 2) {
        return msg.reply('You do not have the proper permissions');
      }

      if (ref.rank >= 3) {
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM chal WHERE id = ?';
        db.query(sql, id, (err, row) => {
          var winner = row[0];
          if (winner === undefined) {
            return msg.reply('This ongoing challenge does not exist! Use the command for the list to find the proper ID');
          } else {
            msg.channel.send(user.username + ' was declared winner on the challenge ' + winner.chalbyname +
            ' VS. ' + winner.chaltoname + ' in a ' + winner.type + ' duel!');
            sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?';
            var chalUser = null;
            if (user.id == winner.chaltoid) {
              console.log(winner.chalbyid);
              chalUser = winner.chalbyid;
            } else {
              chalUser = winner.chaltoid;
            }
            console.log(chalUser);
            db.query(sql, chalUser, (err, row) => {
              chalUser = row[0];
              var winElo = null;
              var lossElo = null;
              var wins = null;
              var loss = null;
              var loserWins = null;
              var loserLoss = null;
              switch (winner.type) {
                case 'mock':
                  winElo = user.melo;
                  lossElo = chalUser.melo;
                  wins = user.winsmock;
                  loss = user.lossmock;
                  loserWins = chalUser.winsmock;
                  loserLoss = chalUser.lossmock;
                  break;
                case 'legit':
                  winElo = user.lelo;
                  lossElo = chalUser.lelo;
                  wins = user.winslegit;
                  loss = user.lossclosed;
                  loserWins = chalUser.winsmock;
                  loserLoss = chalUser.lossmock;
                  break;
                case 'closed':
                  winElo = user.celo;
                  lossElo = chalUser.celo;
                  wins = user.winsclosed;
                  loss = user.lossclosed;
                  loserWins = chalUser.winsmock;
                  loserLoss = chalUser.lossmock;
                  break;
              }
              var eloWin = null;
              var eloLoss = null;
              if (winElo > lossElo || winElo == lossElo) {
                eloWin = Math.ceil(winElo + (winElo / lossElo));
                eloLoss = Math.ceil(lossElo - (winElo / lossElo));
              }

              if (winElo < lossElo) {
                eloWin = Math.ceil(winElo + (winElo - lossElo) / 2);
                eloLoss = Math.ceil(lossElo - (winElo - lossElo) / 5);
              }

              msg.channel.send('WINNER: ' + user.username + 'Old Elo: ' + winElo + ' New Elo: ' + eloWin);
              msg.channel.send('LOSER: ' + chalUser.username +  'Old Elo: ' + lossElo + ' New Elo: ' + eloLoss);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Win;
```

Here is the issue: `console.log(winner.chalbyid)` SHOULD produce the ID of the user who challenged them. The challenge itself puts it into the database (which it does, it is correct). However when I try to set any variable (inside this code) to that ID, it doesn't set it appropriately. Here is what it is setting it to: 
`269662142737678340` 
here is what it should be (as is it is in the database) 
`269662142737678336` 
What is weird is the `console.log(chaltoid);` prints what it should, and works fine. But for some reason, `chalbyid` adds to the total. looks like by four.

EDIT: Okay, so it seems to not add to the ID of exactly ONE member, everyone else is screwed. It adds to their IDs and it is weird. (in my challenge table, not the register users table, that one seems fine).

EDIT: Okay, so I made another similar command, but made it so there isn't so much clutter:

```
  run(msg, { id, user }) {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM chal WHERE id = ?';
    db.query(sql, id, (err, rows) => {
      var test = rows[0];
      msg.channel.send(test.chalbyid);
    });
  }
}
```

However, it is still adding to it. What is weird it only happens on certain members, so far all except one.

EDIT:
Okay, well... I've tested printing out the ID in several locations, even from my register members database. But for some reason, printing out the ID causes it to ADD to to total of it. I have no clue why, but it is the ID that it is only adding to. Sorry, I need to clarify, it is not adding it only on print. It is just adding regardless, which messes up functions because the IDs don't match. If I test against `.author.id` to the id in the database, it works fine. However if I try using that number FROM the database, it adds.

EDIT... Again...: 
I am using `BIGINT(255)` where these ids are stored. What is odd is it doesn't do it one certain person... at least as far as I can (only have 3 test users registered ATM). I just don't understand. Why is it adding? It is displaying the same length, but adding to the total. The ID in the database is right, I've made sure. This makes absolutely no sense.

LITTLE BIT MORE INFO:

Okay so here is the value it won't change: `135810874416824320` length of 18.

Here is the value it will change: `269662142737678336` length of 18. Will change this value to: `269662142737678340`

It will also change this value: `302914419132858368` to `302914419132858400`

Again: It will compare TO the database fine, however it does that weird adding when I pull it out, and try to use it. (In this case snding a message with the ID)... but if I try to compare itself to the userid after pulling it out, it will break my functions... and I kind of need this for the bot to work properly.

Comment: Still looking for a solution. I've tried everything. Nothing seems to make the numbers stay the same. I just don't understand why it even does this, why randomly add to a value  being pulled out of a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing:

I haven't exactly tested this fully. But it seems changing `BIGINT(255)` to `VARCHAR(255)` fixed my issue... Given the value is only 18 in length and BIGINT is supposed to allow 19, it is weird that I had this problem.

Comment: Hey William - can you accept this as your answer so I stop coming back to this question :D